# Cannot invoke append with an argument list of type json in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, functional-programming

When I try to append a list which contain list of image which I parsed from JSON into an array in Swift iOS I mm getting an error:

> "Cannot invoke append with an argument list of type json"

I'm totally new to iOS (Swift).

This is the basic code I'm using Alamofire, SwiftyJSON and SwiftyUserDefaults.

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import SwiftyUserDefaults

var NameArr: [String] = []
var ProfileImgArr: [String] = []
var StyleTypeArr: [String] = []

var ImageStackArr = [String]()
var SingleImageArr: [String] = []

var ItemNameArr: [String] = []
var TagsArr: [String] = []
var ImageArrSet: [String] = []
var LikeCountArr: [Int] = []

var ImageFlag: [String] = []

var testCount: (Int) = 0
var imageCounter = 0
var normalCounter = 0
var normalCounter1 = 0
var normalCounter2 = 0

// JSON load

let url = "http://zapmob.cloudapp.net/media/"

func JsonLoad() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://zapmob.cloudapp.net/feed/?format=json")
        .responseJSON { (request, response,  data, error) in
            println(error)
            println(response)

            let json = JSON(data!)

            for (var j = 0; j <= json.count-1; j++) {
                let FullName = json[j]["user_details_dict"]["username"].string
                self.NameArr.append(FullName!)

                let ProfilePic = json[j]["user_details_dict"]["profile_pic"].string
                self.ProfileImgArr.append(ProfilePic!)

                let StyleType = json[j]["fashion_type"].string
                self.StyleTypeArr.append(StyleType!)

                // -- Start of error part --v

                var ImageStackArrs = [json[j]["images"].array!]

                println(ImageStackArrs)

                Defaults["ImageArrStack"] = ImageStackArrs

                for (var x = 0; x <= ImageStackArrs.count - 1; x++) {
                    Defaults["ImageStackCache"] = [ImageStackArrs[x][0]]
                }

                // -- End of error part --^

                let ItemName = json[j]["album_title"].string
                self.ItemNameArr.append(ItemName!)

                let LikeCount = json[j]["like"].count
                self.LikeCountArr.append(LikeCount)
            }

            Defaults["NameCache"] = self.NameArr
            Defaults["ProfileImgCache"] = self.ProfileImgArr
            Defaults["StyleTypeCache"] = self.StyleTypeArr
            Defaults["ItemNameCache"] = self.ItemNameArr
            Defaults["TagsCache"] = self.TagsArr
            Defaults["LikeCountCache"] = self.LikeCountArr
    }
}
```

Comment: At which line exactly do you get an error?

Comment: @AntonBronnikov 
at this line   Defaults["ImageArrStack"] = ImageStackArrs
Also when i try to append ImageStackArrs to an array

Answer (score 1):

Without going through the code in detail:  This error is normally called when trying to append to an optional array.